# Need Examples for a Statement in HTML5 Specification of the body Element

Tags: html, event-handling, event-bubbling, document-body

I need some examples for me to better understand how event bubbling works on events registered with the <body> element - **In relation to the following paragraph** found in the [HTML5 specification](https://developers.whatwg.org/sections.html#the-body-element).

> Thus, for example, a bubbling error event dispatched on a child of the body element of a Document would first trigger the onerror event handler content attributes of that element, then that of the root html element, and only then would it trigger the onerror event handler content attribute on the body element. This is because the event would bubble from the target, to the body, to the html, to the Document, to the Window, and the event handler on the body is watching the Window not the body. A regular event listener attached to the body using addEventListener(), however, would be run when the event bubbled through the body and not when it reaches the Window object.

I need code that demonstrates the difference described by the following lines from the above paragraph.

> A regular event listener attached to the body using addEventListener(), however, would be run when the event bubbled through the body and not when it reaches the Window object.

Appreciate your help.
TIA
thiru